Astro CLI airflow connction issue on windows
I run an Apache Airflow development setup using Astro CLI, and both the webserver and scheduler are functioning correctly. I can log in and perform tasks without issues. However, I'm encountering a problem when trying to create a database connection to a server on my LAN—it fails.
On the other hand, when I install Airflow directly on WSL2 using pip, the connection works fine.
